# How to convert string to array of string

Tags: arrays, string, go, slice

I am trying to convert a string `["211007@it_4","211008@it_4"]`, which is saved in MySQL database to an array of string to use it as an index value.

I can not find a good way to do this in Go.

Comment: That looks like a JSON array of strings, so how about unmarshaling it using the `encoding/json` package?

Comment: Have you tried to spit the same and then save it into `map[string]string` with string index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input looks like a JSON array with string elements. If that is so, simply use the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package to unmarshal it into a `[]string` variable.

Example:

```
s := `["211007@it_4","211008@it_4"]`
var parts []string
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &parts); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println("elements:", parts)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bi7SCoKAp_Q)):

```
elements: [211007@it_4 211008@it_4]
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard library contains functions to work with strings (e.g. `strings.Trim()` and `strings.Split()`).

See the code - https://play.golang.org/p/vOAzyU4eZbf

Comment: This also removes leading and trailing square brackets that may be part of the first or last string elements such as `["[211007@it_4","211008@it_4"]`.